# phpBB : How to get phpBB feeds to another webpage which is in a parent domain?

Tags: php, forum, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm using phpBB v3.0.12. This is the link to my phpBB forum in my website

```
www.mydomain.com/forum/index.php
```

Whenever there is writing activity in that forum (such as reply to a post/topic or create a new topic), I want to be able to receive those activities' link,subject(max of 10 characters) and post(max of 20 characters) and display it as a list of activites in a subsection in the main page :

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php
```

Is it possible? If so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your server's database, there is a table called `phpbb_posts`. This table contains the topic id, forum id and post id of each post as well as others such as subject and texts.

Just use MySQL to fetch those posts and their descriptions and use the ids to create the link to each post.